# Reverse port forwarding to provide access to apt server

Tags: networking, ssh

I can access a Ubuntu server via a ssh server behind the firewall from home. There is no internet access behind the firewall. I need to use APT to install some packages on the Ubuntu server. How do I use reverse port forwarding to provide internet access to the Ubuntu server?
Here is the illustration of the network. Server=Ubuntu server
[image: network]

Answer (score 0):

one scenario would be to configure http proxy on your ssh server and use it on the ubuntu server:
https://kifarunix.com/how-to-set-system-wide-proxy-in-ubuntu-18-04/

Other scenario for full internet access assuming the ubuntu server doesnt have a gateway but has a connection to the ssh server and the ssh server does have internet since you access it from home.
What you can do is make the ssh server the gateway for the ubuntu and do nat masquerade there and enable ip forwarding that would basically turn your ssh server into a router that does nat for the ubuntu.

here is a helpful link
http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/enable-ip-forwarding-on-ubuntu-13-04/